# Getting passed as list parameters from constructor

Tags: java, constructor

what will be the method to get the parameters of the created Object passed to AnotherClass in the bellow dummy? Thank you.

```
    public main class {
    Group group = new Group(Arrays.asList("FAM","MAF"));

    //some other code

    }

    public class AnotherClass {

    List<String>groupParameters = new ArrayList<String>();

     public AnotherClass(List<String> groupParameters) {
            this.groupParameters = groupParameters;
        }

    //here should be the method to get the passed parameters from the above constructor

    }
```

Comment: just getter method `List<String> getGroupParameters() {return this.groupParamters;}`

Comment: What is relation between Group and AnotherClass ?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comments and answers, the Main contains "public static void main(String[] args)", this is the runner class, I did not include other classes and other code, cos it would be huge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this method to your `AnotherClass` class:

```
public List<String> getGroupParameters() {
    return this.groupParameters;
}
```

If you are using an IDE it's very likely that you can generate automatically those getter/setter methods.